# Calculation of a polynomial in C

Tags: c

while I was doing a practice exercise I ran into a question, the instruction is as follows:

Ask for the value of X and ask for the degree of the polynomial.
Write a function of the form `double polynomial(double x, double n)` that recursively asks for the value of each coefficient and returns the sum of a<sub>n</sub>x<sup>n</sup> from n to 0.

I did my solution with cycles (it is the following) but I have doubts about how I could do it with recursion.

```
for (i = 0; i <= order; i++)
{
    printf("Enter coefficients of polynomial at x^%d\n", i);
    scanf("%f", &coefficient[i]); 
}
  
for (i = 0; i <= order; i++)
{
    sum += coefficient[i] * pow(x, i);
}
```

I attach the block of code that I made with cycles, but I would like to do it with recursion.

Comment: OT: `%f` is not correct for scanning a double. Check the manual.

Comment: OT: Always, always, always.... check the `scanf` return value. Here it must be 1. Otherwise there is an input error, i.e. either a real input error or that the user typed something not being a floating point value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Write a function of the form `double polynomial(double x, double n)`

is a little strange for this task. It should probably be

```
double polynomial(double x, unsigned n);
                            ^^^^^^^^
```

I won't write the whole code but here is some pseudocode for a recursive implementation:

```
double polynomial(double x, unsigned n)
{
     coefficient = read_nth_coefficient_from_user

     if (n == 0) return coefficient

     return (coefficient * (x to the power of n)) + polynomial(x, n - 1)
}
```

Notice the comparison `n == 0` to stop recursion and the `n - 1` when doing the recursive call. These are the reason that `n` should be an `unsigned` instead of a `double`.

### End note

I understand that this is "a practice exercise" so fine, go ahead and use recursion. But a task like this should **not be solved using recursion** in real code. A loop is much better. In general, recursion should be avoided unless it gives you significant benefits. And when recursion is used, take care that the number of recursive calls has a well controlled (and pretty low) limit. A high number of recursive calls may lead to stack overflow. Use recursion with care.

Comment: What is coef= get_nth_coef_from_user?? Excuse me

Comment: @YAHIRJOSUEOSTOSJIMENEZ It's pseudo code for reading in the coefficient for the current level. In principle something like your code: `printf("Enter coefficients of polynomial at x^%d\n",i); scanf("%f",&coefficient[i]);` Just without a loop and without use of an array

Comment: Helpful grammar guidance: your post history has a lot of "shall" in it, and I wonder if it sometimes was not the right word. "Shall" is a prediction of a future event that is known in advance, but "should" is a statement of obligation or correctness. For example: "I shall arrive at 8pm" (strong prediction) versus "I should quit smoking" (out of the obligation to look after oneself).

Comment: In theory one could say "your solution shall not use recursion" on the basis that, after your advice is followed, this future prediction will become true. But it sounds awkward in native English, and does not take into account the possibility that the advice will not be followed (in which case it would be correct to say that the OP's solution shall use recursion, even though this not an optimal solution). In any case, "shall" is missing the element of correctness contained within "should".